# O que significa "@" antes de uma variável no PHP?

Tags: php

Estou olhando um código e me deparei com o seguinte:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Achei que o @ tivesse sido um mistyping, mas quando eu removo o arroba recebo um warning:

> DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity

Estou procurando no manual, mas não acho nada. 
O que esse arroba faz? E qual o nome 'técnico' dele?

Comment: Ele suprime os avisos, por isso quando você usa ele o warning não é exibido.